Vite module loader lacks file extension
In a Sveltekit app (which uses Vite) I use a library, that has an export like this inside its dist folder:
my-app/node_modules/some-lib/dist/foo/index.js
export * from './some-component

So it is a relative path to a js file, that exists in this folder.
I import it in my project like this:
import 'some-lib/dist/foo';

When starting dev server, or building for prod, I get the message, that file my-app/node_modules/some-lib/dist/foo/some-component could not be found - and it is not found because the .js extension is missing. If I add the .js file extension in that export in the index.js file of the component lib, then it would work.
I can also say that relative imports work perfectly fine without any file extensions in my project files. But that component lib in my node_modules folder has some problem with it.
Defining that resolve config in Vite does not help too.
Any ideas how I can solve this without editing the component lib?

The problem is likely caused by the vite SSR step. Edit your vite.config.ts with:
... defineConfig({
  plugins: [ ... ],
  ssr: {
    noExternal: [
      "some-lib,
    ],
  },
})

Similar issue here: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/16190
